# How to make a Pivot Table in Visual Basic

Tags: sql, vb.net, gridview, pivot-table

i´ve got a doubt. I made a Pivot Table with Transform in SQL and now wanted to export it to my VB project. The thing is that according to my teacher I won´t be able to insert that Pivot Table into a Form. She says that i will need to either create a DataGridView or do it in a Listbox.

My pivot table would contain in the rows the Room Type (we are simulating an small hotel and we want to see de income by months) and in the columns the months.

I was wondering if someone has any idea on how i can display this data in a nice way.

Thanks!

Comment: My advice, listen to your teacher.   The pivot table you've extracted will effectively become the data source for a UI component such as a DataGridView.  There may be other controls around that are specifically designed for pivots but even so it's still a UI component

Comment: Do you have sample data and the expected output for pivot. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Whether your "pivot table" is an actual table or just the result set of a query, it's still just data from a database. As far as a VB application is concerned, any data coming from a database is the same, regardless of how it was generated. How do you usually display data from a database? That's how you display this data. Stop looking for some magic solution that is specific to a pivot table. Data is data.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions.I ended up transforming my Pivot Table into a Table. using SELECT * FROM "Pivot Table" INTO "New_Table".